# ng-repeat values evaluated outside by ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do you access ng-repeat data for conditional settings outside the ng-repeat directive scope? For instance, I would like to show a div block outside ng-repeat when someone selects a radio button generated within ng-repeat.

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.obj = [{
    condition: "Question1",
    status: "no"
  }, {
    condition: "Question2",
    status: "no"
  }];
}
```

---

.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="o in obj">
  <td>{{o.condition}}</td>
  <td>
    Yes
    <input type="radio" ng-model="o.status" value="yes" /> No
    <input type="radio" ng-model="o.status" value="no" />
  </td>
</tr>

<!-- this will show based on an input event-->
<div ng-if="o.status == 'yes'" class="myClass">
I show up
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fergnab/jmb619qg/

Comment: You want to show the additional `div` depending on which question?

Comment: Yes, I would like to show a div (or any element) outside of the ng-repeat via the selection of the radio = 'yes'. Thanks

Comment: you (can) have multiple questions `o` in `obj`. Which `yes` setting should show the additional div? Or maybe each `o` in `obj` when set to `yes` should show a new div?

Comment: Exactly, imagine if the user selects question one; the div will be div1 and if they select question two, div2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. But you can try something like this.

add function that will check if obj have question with "ok" status

html

```
<div ng-if="someQuestionIsOk()" class="myClass">
```

controller

```
$scope.someQuestionIsOk = function someQuestionIsOk() {

   for(var i = 0; i < $scope.obj.length; i++) {
       if($scope.obj[i].status == 'yes')
           return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

**EDIT**

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8xf2myr/6/)

**EDIT**

yet another possible solution is to use ng-change.

html

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="o.status" ng-change="statusChange(o)" value="yes" />
```

controller

```
 $scope.answerIsYes = false;

 $scope.statusChange = function statusChange(object) {
     if(object.status == 'yes')
         $scope.answerIsYes = true;
     else 
         $scope.answerIsYes = $scope.someQuestionIsOk();         
 }
```

Comment: this is very good, but I am pretty sure the it can be done... I was thinking about the $watch function on ng-if and working a possible solution from your js sample

Comment: why use watcher when you can call function using ng-change on input

Comment: That was what i was thinking; I am trying it now

Answer (score 1):

What I have here works locally, but not when I try it in js fiddle - I'm not sure why.

app.js (this is how I'm used to defining controllers):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.obj = [{
    condition: "Question0",
    status: "no"
  }, {
    condition: "Question1",
    status: "no"
  }];
});
```

index.html (make a separate `h1` for each `o` in `obj`):

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Question</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="o in obj">
          <td>{{o.condition}}</td>
          <td>
            Yes <input type="radio" ng-model="o.status" value="yes" />
            No <input type="radio" ng-model="o.status" value="no" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- this will display "question 0" and/or "question 1", based on input -->
    <div ng-repeat="o in obj">
      <h1 ng-if="obj[$index].status === 'yes'" class="myClass">
        question {{$index}}
      </h1>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```